# Badge Suggestion: Jon Skeet Programming Prize

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badge-request

This badge would be optionaly awarded to one user annually (or monthly, or other period).  The recipient would be chosen by Jon Skeet and perhaps a committee of moderators appointed by Jon Skeet to a user who has greatly contributed to Stack Overflow and the greater programming community. In addition to the badge, the recipient is awarded either: (A) A small portion of Jon Skeet's rep, (B) the amount of additional rep Jon Skeet would have accumulated since the last prize was awarded if there was no daily rep cap, or (C) a combination of A and B.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds this hero worship embarrassing?

Comment: This is a **suggestion**. I don't see why it's getting close votes.

Comment: @Michael No, you are not.

Comment: "the amount of additional rep Jon Skeet would have accumulated since the last prize was awarded if there was no daily rep cap" That's like over 400 points a day

Comment: If it were like 300 points per day then there should be a maximum that could be awarded.

Comment: @NullUserException: I've just looked at the rep report - 38383 capped votes, over 725 days. So just under 530 per day, on average.

Comment: @Jon I figured it would be in the ballpark. You'd probably cap daily even if you didn't post anything, wouldn't you?

Comment: @NullUserException: During the week, yes. Less likely at weekends. As I tweeted recently, if 0.2% of my answers are upvoted in a given day, that hits the rep cap. Gotta love the long tail. Obviously the longer I didn't post for, the less likely it would be - recent posts are much more likely to receive votes.

Comment: @Michael, I'm not saying this is the same, but this type of thing is not unprecedented - sports are full of them.  Naismith, Heisman, Cy Young, etc.  Of course in those cases the name is an honor only, the award is not picked by the namesake.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there's any need to single me out around this. The [SO leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stack-overflow) have made it very clear that there are plenty of other users getting roughly the same rep as me per month. Nick Craver's been consistently beating my rep for the last couple of months, although he's currently being distracted by silly things like getting married and moving house.

I've just been consistently "around the top" for a long time.

Having an occasional discretionary award (a bounty for the system that Jeff could award for particularly amazing answers) is fine, but I don't think it needs to be associated with me. (Don't forget that users who don't read the tags I'm active in may not have even heard of me...)

Comment: +1 for silly things! (I'm constantly distracted since the birth of my daughter...)

Comment: +1 For a long long time I was like, who is Jon Skeet and why is everybody talking about him.

Comment: Just asking, is there such thing as [tag:JonSkeet]

Answer (score 3):

The idea is interesting, but if the stakes are high (badge + rep percentage), a subjective decision by a committee is likely to be **controversial**.

I don't have a better idea though.