# What is the median reputation growth rate, ratio'ed to question and answer count, for a static stackoverflow account?

Tags: discussion, reputation, growth

I have a relatively static stackoverflow account.  I ask the occasional question and give that occasional answer but not often.  Early on I was more active, so I have about 100 questions and about 200 answers.  My reputation continuously make a steady climb without me adding much.  The set of questions and answers continuously generates reputation.

I was wondering if this reputation inflation had ever been measured.  What is the inflation and how does it relate to the number of questions and answers?

Comment: I don't have exact figures, but I know Jon Skeet reaches the reputation cap daily *without posting anything*. Seriously. (see the comments on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65138/badge-suggestion-jon-skeet-programming-prize-closed))

Comment: I would be very interested to see a graph showing average reputation growth rate over time.  I'm particularly interested in the rough point where reputation begins to grow significantly on its own.  It's kinda like when you have enough money that your money begins to earn enough income on its own.